# This page is not shared with you while user doing a search in webapplication

Tags: sharepoint

When user doing a search on web application user getting Error like this page is not shared with you. User have enough permissions on the web app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article for your reference, which may help you.

- [Solution “Sorry, this site hasn’t been shared with you.”](https://sharepointdevelopmentblog.wordpress.com/2020/01/10/solution-sorry-this-site-hasnt-been-shared-with-you/)